# StreamingHttpResponse: return database connection to pool / close it

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pytest, gevent

If you have a `StreamingHttpResponse` returned from a Django view, when does it return any database connection to the pool? If by default it does it once the `StreamingHttpResponse` has completed, is there a way to make return the connection earlier?

```
def my_view(request):
  # Some database queries using the Django ORM
  # ...

  def yield_data():
    # A generator, with no database queries using the Django ORM
    # ...

  return StreamingHttpResponse(
    yield_data(), status=200
  )
```

If it makes a difference, this is using https://pypi.org/project/django-db-geventpool/ with gunicorn, and any answer should also work when tested with `pytest.mark.django_db` (that I think wraps tests in transactions)

Comment: You should not *call* `yield_data`, since then it will of course first evaluate the function `yield_data` (until the end).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `yield_data` is a generator (i.e. with `yield` inside the definition). I think calling it won't do anything until the return value of calling it is iterated over? I have added a comment to make it clearer it's a generator.

Comment: @MichaCharemza: ah yes, then it is indeed correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the documentation

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/

**Connection management**

> Django opens a connection to the database when it first makes a database query. It keeps this connection open and reuses it in subsequent requests. Django closes the connection once it exceeds the maximum age defined by CONN_MAX_AGE or when it isn’t usable any longer.
>
> In detail, Django automatically opens a connection to the database whenever it needs one and doesn’t have one already — either because this is the first connection, or because the previous connection was closed.
>
> At the beginning of each request, Django closes the connection if it has reached its maximum age. If your database terminates idle connections after some time, you should set CONN_MAX_AGE to a lower value, so that Django doesn’t attempt to use a connection that has been terminated by the database server. (This problem may only affect very low traffic sites.)
>
> At the end of each request, Django closes the connection if it has reached its maximum age or if it is in an unrecoverable error state. If any database errors have occurred while processing the requests, Django checks whether the connection still works, and closes it if it doesn’t. Thus, database errors affect at most one request; if the connection becomes unusable, the next request gets a fresh connection.

Also if you see the `db/__init__.py` in `django` source code

```py
# For backwards compatibility. Prefer connections['default'] instead.
connection = DefaultConnectionProxy()


# Register an event to reset saved queries when a Django request is started.
def reset_queries(**kwargs):
    for conn in connections.all():
        conn.queries_log.clear()


signals.request_started.connect(reset_queries)


# Register an event to reset transaction state and close connections past
# their lifetime.
def close_old_connections(**kwargs):
    for conn in connections.all():
        conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()


signals.request_started.connect(close_old_connections)
signals.request_finished.connect(close_old_connections)
```

It has connection to the `request_started` and `request_finished` signal to close old connections using `close_old_connections`.

So if you are not willing to wait for connections to be closed you can call this method yourself. You updated code will be like below

```py
from django.db import close_old_connections

def my_view(request):
  # Some database queries using the Django ORM
  # ...
  close_old_connections()

  def yield_data():
    # A generator, with no database queries using the Django ORM
    # ...

  return StreamingHttpResponse(
    yield_data(), status=200
  )
```

Comment: Would `close_old_connections` cause any problems if `my_view` is wrapped in a transaction, as in from `pytest.mark.django_db` ?

Comment: Skimming through the code, it looks like it should not have an impact on your tests. If you have any issues, let me know